# Magento site note loading all sections/blocks after moving it to amazon AWS

Tags: magento-1.9, aws

I have moved my local magento site to Amazon AWS. After moving, my site is not loading with all sections/blocks(Products listing and slider/banner) in site front end. I am using themevast theme. Can any one help me to solve this? What could be the reason for this?

Comment: did you empty cache, recompile and so on ?

Comment: Thanks@ChristopheFerreboeuf,I've cleared cache but not recompiled.Let me recompile.

Comment: @ChristopheFerreboeuf, i have compiled but still problem exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution to this problem.
I was getting errors like `future time stamp in` and `Exiting with failure status because of previous errors.` This is may be because of file permissions(read/write/execute).

I was trying to extract `filename.tar.gz`. It was having these issues. Later i created `filename.zip` and unzip using `unzip` command. Now everything is working.

Answer (score 0):

Out of caching and compilation there can be many different issues :

- some files or folder were not copied correctly (maybe /media/ in your case)
- the theme is not correctly set in back-office
- some links were provided with full address instead of relative
- the new server has its own fpc that was filled partially before the complete copy
- some things were still compiled on the old server and were deleted
- many other site specific reasons (can you provide the address ?)

Comment: Please check this `morascala.com`

Comment: I'm getting 500 error when i try to start compilation process and same error when i try to edit product or create product from admin panel. I think one issue causing all problems. I'm suspecting that this is because of directory/file permission issue.

Comment: @Christoohe Ferreboeuf Found solution to this.

Comment: so ? was it permission problem ?

Comment: No, it was not extracted fully and failed in middle.